# Does this StackOverFlowException require pointers to correctly work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I made a program that searches for palindromes by reading in from a .txt file, then placing output onto a separate .txt file.

It works just as it should with about 50 or so characters. But if I copy and past a large amount of words onto the .txt file for it to read, at runtime it will say "Process is terminated due to StackOverFlowException". Then it opens a file called chkstk.asm and has a arrow pointing to something called- "test dword ptr [eax], eax ; probe page". Next a box comes up with a break and continue option and says, "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in palindrone.exe"

I am currently working on changing things around to use pointers and such and possibly store things in vectors. However, I am still not sure what the reason for the error is and I want to know why it is acting up and what needs to be changed so I can have it read and process large blocks of text. Is not having pointers the reason for it working incorrectly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/**
    Recursivly reverses a string
    @ param word, the word being entered
    @ last_char, the last character currently in the string
    @ go, the recursive function to return the character and continue inside itself
**/
string string_reverse(string word)
{
    if (word.length() - 1 > 0)
    {
        char last_char = word[word.length()-1];
        word.erase(word.length()-1);
        string go = string_reverse(word);
        return go.insert(0, 1, last_char);
    }
    else  
        return word.substr(0,1);
}

/**
@param in, the input as the original string
@param la, the reverse string
**/
bool equals(string in, string la)
{
    if(in == la)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

/**
processes the pal
**/
void process_pal(ofstream &outfile, string in, string la, bool sam)
{
    if (sam == true)
    {
        outfile << in << " EQUAL to backwards: " << la << "\n";
    }
    else
        outfile << in << " NOT equal to backwards: " << la << "\n";
}

/**
    Removes all Numbers, white spaces, and invalid symbols with !isalpha
    @param sentence, the sentence being entered
    @ it, the iterator to iterator through the sentence checking for invlaid sysmbols
**/
string remover(string sentence)
{
    string::iterator it = sentence.begin();

    while (it != sentence.end())
    {
         while( it != sentence.end() && !isalpha(*it))
         {
             it = sentence.erase(it);
         }
         if (it != sentence.end())
             ++it;
    }
return sentence;
}

/**
    Increments to find paladrome by starting at 3 from 0, then moving right 1 by 3 each time util
    it goes to the end. Once it hits the end, it will increment by four and do the same thing till
    it has become the full length of the text.
**/
void find_pal(ofstream &outfile, string input, int pos, int lin)
{
    int max_length = input.length()+1;
    int pos_last = max_length - lin;
    if(lin < input.length()){
        string sub_fwrd = input.substr(pos,lin);
        string sub_bck = string_reverse(sub_fwrd);
        bool same = equals(sub_fwrd, sub_bck);
        process_pal(outfile, sub_fwrd, sub_bck, same);
        pos++;
        if (pos == pos_last){
            pos = 0;
            lin++;
        }
        find_pal(outfile, input, pos, lin);
}
}

int main()
{
    bool con = true;
    while (con == true)
    {
        string input;
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open ("file_read.txt");    
        getline(infile,input); // Saves the lines from the file in string input.
        infile.close();

        transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::tolower); // Goes to all Lower Case

        string inputer = remover(input); // Removes unwanted symbols, numbers, spaces, etc
        input = inputer; // Updates our orignal string input

        ofstream outfile ("file_out.txt");
        int pos = 0;
        int lin = 3;
        find_pal(outfile, input, pos, lin); // Start the palindron function up to sift       through purmutations

        string full_input = string_reverse(input); // Final Purmutation of reverse
        bool same = equals(input, full_input);
        process_pal(outfile, input, full_input, same); // Final analyzing process_pal

        string go;
        outfile.close();    
        cout << "Continue? y/n " << endl; // Continue on or not
        getline(cin, go);
        if(go != "y")
            con = false;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like Visual C++ so I'm going to add the tag for it.

Comment: I don't think that pointers are required to get a StackOverflowException.

Comment: Yes, I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express. Thanks for adding it.

Comment: No, You have too many recursive calling(find_pal).Palindromes don't need recursive search.

Comment: Rewrite recursive methods that can go very, very deep to be iterative if you are getting stackoverflowexceptions.

Comment: So  find_pal() and all other recursive functions need to be rewritten iteratively. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you so addicted to recursion? Every single function that you have there could be implemented more efficiently and less boilerplate if you'd use iterative approach. Furthermore, learn to write simple test cases every time you create a new unit of functionality (be it method, class, or whatever). Otherwise, you'll drown in bug chains which are difficult and time consuming to untangle. Enjoy the bug tracking marathon.

Comment: Plus 1 for mentioning StackOverflow in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ there is a stack and a heap.  The stack is typically a fixed size segment of memory that is probably smaller than you might think (defaults can be around 1-2MB) and the heap is a  dynamic section of memory that grows right on up until you exceed the total logical RAM on the server.

The short answer to your question is that each time you nest a function call you allocate a little bit more memory in what is called a "stack frame".  So if you have "main calls A calls B calls B again" then you have 4 stack frames.  If you have a recursive method which grows with the size of your input then you will start to allocate a lot of stack frames and eventually you will have a stack overflow exception (the size of the stack has exceeded the fixed limit).

So, in general, the root cause of your problem is that your recursion is nesting too deeply.  There are a couple of ways of working around this.  One common way that has been mentioned in comments is to simply abandon recursion.  Another approach is to use [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) which avoids adding a new stack frame with each call and allows you to keep the recursive semantics.

All that being said, I should mention that you might see a *small* benefit if you were to switch to pointers.  This is because the stack frame's size is based on the size of your function parameters and local variables.  A pointer might be smaller than some other structure you are passing in and could result in a smaller stack frame.  However, this is not the root cause of your problem.

Comment: I'm a pedantic jerk, so I'm just going to point out that, in C and C++ *implementations* there *typically exists* a stack and a heap.  There is no such requirement in the language spec.

Comment: That is true, thank you.  In addition to that comment, it should be noted that C++ implementations *can* optimize tail recursion but that is not required either.  However, most modern compilers will.

Comment: Nice. I understand. Thanks for telling about tail recursion. I am checking it out now.